# Pandas - Create columns from column value, and fill with count

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have a dataframe similar to below.

`Index    Time    Weekday
0      21:10:00    Tuesday
1      21:15:00    Tuesday
2      21:20:00    Tuesday
3      21:20:00    Tuesday
4      21:25:00  Wednesday
5      21:25:00  Wednesday
6      21:30:00     Friday
7      21:35:00   Thursday
8      21:35:00  Wednesday
9      21:40:00  Wednesday
10     21:40:00  Wednesday
11     21:40:00  Monday`

I want to put the weekdays into columns, and count how many times each time appears for each day, my goal is this:

`Time         Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday
21:10:00      0       1      0          0        0
21:15:00      0       1      0          0        0
21:20:00      0       2      0          0        0
21:25:00      0       0      2          0        0
21:30:00      0       0      0          0        1
21:35:00      0       0      1          1        0
21:40:00      1       0      2          0        0`

The reason for this is because I want to create a heatmap in seaborn, and I read my data has to be pivoted/shaped a certain way:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37790707/9384889

I know how to count how frequent each `Time` value appears, ignoring the weekday:
`df['Time'].value_counts()`
 And I have been reading http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html
But I cannot see how to combine these two ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) or [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) alternative for reshape.

For change order of days need [`ordered Categorical`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) or [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) by columns:

```
cats = ['Monday','Tuesday','Wednesday','Thursday','Friday']

df['Weekday'] = pd.Categorical(df['Weekday'], categories=cats, ordered=True)

df = df.groupby(['Time', 'Weekday']).size().unstack(fill_value=0)
```

---

```
df = df.groupby(['Time', 'Weekday']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reindex(columns=cats)
```

Alternatives:

```
df = pd.crosstab(df['Time'], pd.Categorical(df['Weekday'], categories=cats, ordered=True))

df = pd.crosstab(df['Time'], df['Weekday']).reindex(columns=cats)
```

---

```
print (df)

col_0     Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday
Time                                                  
21:10:00       0        1          0         0       0
21:15:00       0        1          0         0       0
21:20:00       0        2          0         0       0
21:25:00       0        0          2         0       0
21:30:00       0        0          0         0       1
21:35:00       0        0          1         1       0
21:40:00       1        0          2         0       0
```

Last use [`seaborn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.heatmap(df, annot=True, fmt="g", cmap='viridis')
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Above and beyond, thank you. I wanted the times on the bottom so I used sns.heatmap(df.T, ...)