# When creating a seaborn heatmap 'could not convert string to float' ValueError

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

Hi everyone I have the following dataframe and I want to create heatmap from it with the following code.

[image: My DataFrame]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
g = sns.heatmap(
    top_5_stations_hourly_total_traffic_by_time, 
    square=True,
    cbar_kws={'fraction' : 0.01},
    cmap='OrRd',
    linewidth=1
)

g.set_xticklabels(top_5_stations_hourly_total_traffic_by_time.STATION, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
g.set_yticklabels(top_5_stations_hourly_total_traffic_by_time.TIME, rotation=45, horizontalalignment='right')
```

But it gives the following error :

> > > ValueError: could not convert string to float: '125 ST'

Comment: I converted station and time columns to categorical types but it gives same error. I want to plot for every station's  , every unique time's hourly total traffic value.

Comment: You should have a look at this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790429/seaborn-heatmap-using-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pivot` your data before calling `heatmap`:

```
df_heatmap = df.pivot("STATION", "TIME", "HOURLY_TOTAL_TRAFFIC")

>>> sns.heatmap(df_heatmap)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much :)

Comment: @UğurSelimÖzen - Happy to help! :)

Comment: Why should that work?

Comment: Because the data is formatted (i.e. laid out) as required by the package.