# Plotting Heatmap from Pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, seaborn, heatmap

How can I make a Heatmap using Seaborn and Padas Dataframe which shows the values (same as in Dataframe) in that plot?

Comment: Did you try https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html ? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
df_heatmap = sns.heatmap(df1, annot=True, cmap="Greens")
plt.title('Heatmap of performance rates with respect to epochs and learning rates', fontsize = 15) # title with fontsize 20
plt.xlabel('Epochs', fontsize = 20) # x-axis label with fontsize 15
plt.ylabel('learning rates', fontsize = 20) # y-axis label with fontsize 15

plt.show()

Comment: This is my code and after running with this code, i am getting the right heatmap what i wanted. Thank you and I appreciate for your response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [seaborn heatmap using pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37790429/seaborn-heatmap-using-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: yes, got it. Thank you !